# How can you wget a file and execute it directly while giving arguments?

Tags: command-line, scripts, wget

I want to download an executable and execute it in one step, while providing arguments to the executable.

I managed to figure out to download+execute by using a pipe:

```
wget -O - http://xrl.us/cpanm | perl
```

This executes the `cpanm` executable via `perl`.

Now I want to add an argument, say `A`:

```
wget -O - http://xrl.us/cpanm | perl A
```

This no longer works. I am now getting `Cannot write to ‘-’ (Success).`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put *perl* script arguments after `programname` which in this case is the standard input (`-`). So, I think, this is what you ask:

```
wget -O - http://xrl.us/cpanm | perl -- - A
```

or

```
wget -O - http://xrl.us/cpanm | perl -- - --help
```

See: [perlrun man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man1/perlrun.1.html) for more details.

***Note:*** From the manual page:

> A "--" signals the end of options and disables further option
>   processing. Any arguments after the "--" are treated as filenames and
>   arguments.

In other words, `--` terminates the *perl* arguments. After that we put the file name containing the script (in our case this is the standard input which is indicated by a `-`) and then the arguments to the script.